# Is there a tf.gather() equivalent for TF datasets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, h5py

I'm currently trying to use precomputed word embeddings, loaded from an h5py file. The embeddings are precomputed for each example in the dataset, so I'm trying to retrieve the embeddings by their example/sequence ID. However, the embeddings are quite large, so I've run into the problem where I can't just run tf.gather() directly on the embeddings to get the ones I want after I retrieve them from the file, since TF won't generate a tensor greater than 2GB. As a result, I'm trying to use the following code:

```
  # precompute_ds is just the tensor of word embeddings
  precompute_ds = h5py.File(kwargs['precompute_path'], 'r')['precomputed']
  precompute_place = tf.placeholder(precompute_ds.dtype, 
                                    shape=precompute_ds.shape)
  word_emb = tf.gather(precompute_place, sequence_ids)
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(word_emb, feed_dict={precompute_place: precompute_ds})

return word_emb
```

However, since `precompute_ds` is an h5py dataset, I'm not sure how to initialize an iterator for it and get the following error:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): GetNext() failed
because the iterator has not been initialized. Ensure that you have run
the initializer operation for this iterator before getting the next element.
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext}} = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=
[[?], [?], [?]], output_types=[DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64], 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](IteratorV2)]]
```

So, I also tried using the following code, following [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays) on the TF website:

```
  precompute_ds = h5py.File(kwargs['precompute_path'], 'r')['precomputed']
  precompute_place = tf.placeholder(precompute_ds.dtype, 
                                    shape=precompute_ds.shape)
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(precompute_place)
  word_emb = tf.gather(ds, sequence_ids)
  it = ds.make_initializable_iterator()
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(it.initializer, feed_dict={precompute_place: precompute_ds})

return word_emb
```

However, there are two problems with this: for one, I'm pretty sure that even if `tf.gather` did work on TF Datasets, this wouldn't properly populate `word_emb`. What I'm thinking now is that I could populate `ds` properly using the second method, but I then don't know how to get exactly the `sequence_ids` I want for this particular batch. Are there any suggestions for either of these two approaches to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: `precompute_ds` is a `h5py` dataset.  `precompute_ds[aslice]` is a `numpy` array, all or part of the dataset.  A dataset accepts most, though not all, `numpy` style slicing and indexing.  I don't know, though, how that plays with `tensorflow`.

Comment: Note that `tf.placeholder` inserts a placeholder for a tensor **that will be always fed** (emphasis mine). It does not contain tensor data. In other words, you created a **placeholder** with the same `dtype` and `shape` as the h5 dataset, **not** a numpy array of data. `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` needs the data...in this case a slice from `precompute_ds`. You will have to interrogate the `precompute_ds ` dataset to find the indices to the sequence IDs, then use to slice. It is hard to be more specific w/out knowing what your data looks like.